# I can't create a organization and publish data in ckan

Tags: organization, ckan

I'm doing an installation of Ckan through the image docker.

I install with ansible, and install some extensions like ckanext-geoview, harvest, pdf-view.

The installation runs fine, but when I register on the ckan site I can not create an organization and a load data.

This my [ckan page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcaSk.jpg)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Is your user created as sysadmin?
If not please use :

```
paster sysadmin add *your_username* -c /path/to/ini
```